# PostgreSQL Commands Providing No Result

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

In my database, there is a table that provides no result whenever I issue a query through the command line.

For example, if I type:

```
select * from <table>
```

Nothing happens. The terminal stops responding until I press `^C` to cancel the request.

All the other tables work fine, I am not sure what is causing this error. It just started happening out of nowhere.

Comment: What happens with `select * from <table> limit 1;` - with `limit 1` and with semicolon?

Comment: The terminal just sits there with no response.

Comment: Then please add your version of Postgres and psql, the exact name and definition of the table and the result of `SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('<table>'));` Also, any concurrent activity? There may be locks ... Look at: `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;` and `SELECT * FROM pg_locks;`

Comment: I have posted a solution that I believe solves the problem. Please let me know if I have made any mistake.

Comment: Just to be sure: you do use a trailing `;` to end the statement?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found a way to solve it.

First run:

```
select * from pg_locks where not granted;
```

Then, from that table, find the relation id. It should be in the column under relation.

Then run this command:

```
select * from pg_locks where relation = <relationid>;
```

After that, determine the pid of the relation that has granted equal to true. There should be a granted column with boolean t and f values. Determine that relation's pid.

Finally, run:

```
select pg_terminate_backend(<pid>);
```

Then, you should now be able to access the table.

Comment: Start with `select * from pg_locks where relation = '<table>'::regclass;`. And also have a look at `pg_stat_activity` to check what the session with `pid = X` actually does before you terminate it ... If it's "idle in transaction", someone / something started a transaction and left it in limbo without commit / rollback. May be something to investigate.

Comment: A `select` can only be blocked, by an exclusive lock on the table. The connection holding that lock most probably issued a DDL statement that wasn't committed.